# Deploy ClickOnce application on an isolated server with mage.exe

Tags: clickonce, mage

I need to publish a ClickOnce application on a server where I cannot install Visual Studio and that I cannot reach with the Visual Studio that I have on my computer. The server is on an isolated network and I can put files on it only with USB.

Is it possibile to install mage.exe or mageui.exe on that server without installing Visual Studio?
If yes, where can I find an installer for that?

I made some tests with mage, deploying the app on my computer, then copying it on another pc that have visual studio installed, and editing the *.application file, and of course it worked, so i got the correct procedure.

My only doubt is about having mage on that server bu no VS.

Application is based on .NET 4.8 Framework with a Test Certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was installing the .NET framework developer pack edition, mage comes with it.